# TypeError: Error #1010 in AS3 in accordion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, accordion, typeerror

I had created Accordion in flash. and I am getting following error

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at accordionSub_fla::accordionMain_1/mouserOver()
```

But, this error is only reflecting on Panel3, I have 9 Panels, all of them are working fine except Panel3 and this Panel3 is not opening only. Below is the code of function

```
function mouserOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
var overed:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
for(var i:int=0; i<numChildren; i++)
{
    var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(getChildAt(i));
    if(mc.props.ind <= overed.props.ind)
    {
        TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:mc.props.lx, ease:Expo.easeOut});
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(mc.props.links);
        myTimer.start();
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, urlAction);
        function urlAction(evt:TimerEvent)
        {
            navigateToURL(request, 'myFrame');
        }

    }
    else
    {
        TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:mc.props.rx, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    }
}}
```

Any immediate response will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is numChildren's value come from?

check these lines:
 var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(getChildAt(i));
    if(mc.props.ind <= overed.props.ind)

mc can be null in some condition, and access its property will fire an error.

Comment: numChildren is total number of panels. values for mc is already defined.

Comment: debug and find if any variable undefined while running

Comment: no such error.. the problem is its just nor working with panel3.. debugging stops at  if(mc.props.ind <= overed.props.ind)

Comment: check the value/type of mc.props.ind and overed.props.ind

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.. there is no error on the code. actually when-ever I am clicking on button it gives an error and I made Panel3's heading as button, so it was firing an error. Now, I made it simple text field, now the problem is solved.

anyways, thanks Frank